# How to switch databases from 'public' in the griddb shell client

Tags: griddb

Hi I've been playing around on a small project in nodejs that would fetch results from a public api and store in a table in gridddb. I've got this to "work" as I've been able to store the data into a table however I quickly realized all my data was being saved to the default 'public' database. I want to be able to expand the number of projects I use griddb for in the future so I want to have separate databases.

I've ran the sql command to create a database from the client with `sql create database <dbname>` and it doesn't throw any errors however I'm not sure how to access it.